# Command that displays character encoding set in the bash terminal

Tags: character-encoding, command, git-bash

what command in git bash that shows its
character encoding use. I know that you need to right click then click options>text and you'll see the character set. but i want to display it into terminal by using what command.
thank you !

Comment: Depends on the terminal.

Comment: I want to display the character set that is used in the git bash terminal